# How to save request and response of a WCF Service into DB table

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF Service which is cosumed by some client.
Now i wanted to log the details(request and response) of this service call for every request.

I am trying to log using soapextensiontypes in web.config

```
<webServices>
  <soapExtensionTypes>
    <add type="Namespace.Classname,Assemblyename" priority="1" group="High"/>
  </soapExtensionTypes>
</webServices>
```

But some how,i am unable to log.

Is there any thing i am missing in web.config

do we need to add soapextension at client(who consumes the WCF service)?

Comment: I'm not sure `SoapExtensions` would work with WCF - I've used them in the past with ASMX but not WCF.  You could look into the WCF extension points like IDispatchMessageInspector and IClientMessageInspector.  Check out [WCF Extensibility – Message Inspectors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/19/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors.aspx) by Carlos Figueira ( he is part of the WCF team, or was, IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

The best way i have found to do this is, like it was pointed out in a comment, using IDispatchMessageInspector and IClientMessageInspector.

```
//First you will need to implement 2 interfaces
//IDispatchMessageInspector or IClientMessageInspector and IServiceBehavior or IEndpointBehavior

public class MustUnderstandMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {

        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            //Here you can use the ref request(Remember it is a ref, careful what you do with it)
            //request is the message you just received
            SaveInDatabase(request);
            return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            //reply is a ref like request and it is the message you are sending
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

// To be able to implement your MessageInspector in your service you need to create a behavior.
//this behavior will have to be added to your server.

public class UnderstandBehavior : IServiceBehavior
    {


        void IServiceBehavior.AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
            //This will Add your inspector to every dispatcher inside serviceHostBase
            //you will have to use the one your service is on
            foreach (ChannelDispatcher chDisp in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
            {
                foreach (EndpointDispatcher epDisp in chDisp.Endpoints)
                {
                    epDisp.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new MustUnderstandMessageInspector());
                }
            }
        }

        void IServiceBehavior.Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have both interfaces done you will have to add the behavior to your service.

```
            svcHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), eventendpoint);
            svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new WSHttpBinding, "Endpoint");
            //Add Service Behavior
            UnderstandBehavior behavior = new UnderstandBehavior();
            svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
            //////
            svcHost.Open();
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "\n\nService is Running";
            svcHost.Close();
    }
```

This is done programatically, to add the behavior in the app.config it would be something like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="ServiceBehavior" type="Namespace.UnderstandBehavior"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehavior"></behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

To implement this on your projecto(or any) you just have to add the MessageInspector and Behavior classes inside your Main Class(form1.cs for example), then you have to add the Config part to your App.config inside the *system.serviceModel* part, put it before the bindings(ej: http://pastebin.com/7KS24CmW ).

Comment: Thanks a lot Borja for the answer.i tried in similar fashion.But  dont know why,I am unable to get the solution.Can you please provide me a sample project file.That would be very very much helpful.Thank much in advance

Comment: I have updated my answer, but i cannot give you a project file right now.

Comment: I derived the UnderstandBehavior class from BehaviorExtensionElement and changed <behavior name="ServiceBehavior"></behavior> to <ServiceBehavior /> in the web.config to make this work